# How to use nested ng-repeat to allow access to second list only when first is successfully answered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new in AngularJS and need to develop a questionnaire.
At the beginning we have access only to the question with category A, others are 'read-only'.
To access the question with category B, we need to give the correct answer to the question with category A etc.  The order can change: it means that questions with category B can be before A for different reasons.

My logic:

```
forEach(q in questions){ //iterate all questions
    if(q.getCategory() == 'A' && q.isCorrect()){ // I have a function which check if  question with category is 'A' and if answer of question with category'A' is correct
        for(q in questions){ //as the order of questions can change I need iterate again all question to find question with category 'B' 
            if(q.getCategory() =='B'){
                do something  //I want to also change css 
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How do we accomplish that using AngularJS? Should I do this in view or maybe should I create a directive?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/MyModuleScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body  ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-repeat="q in questions">
            <span> {{q.content}}</span>
            <div ng-if=q.getCategory() == 'A' && q.isCorrect()>
                <div ng-repeat="q in questions">
                    <div if(q.getCategory() =='B') class ="..">     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your logic. `Finally` you are doing operations on `all questions with  category B`. Then why are you filtering `questions with  category A and Correct`.

Comment: To have access to question with category B, first I need first check if answer to question with category A is correct.

Comment: Thanks notes and help appreciation statements are considered as noise and need not be present in the question. Do not add tag names in the title as they are already present as part of tags. I've reworded the title to better explain your problem. I've also corrected a few typo errors and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, to change css you can use `ng-class` or `ng-style`.

```
<div ng-repeat="a in questions | filter:{'category':'A', 'isCorrect': true}">
  <div ng-repeat="b in questions | filter:{'category':'B'}">{{b}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As ram said he gave you idea. But its better you use the inner ng-repeat in following way.

```
 <div ng-repeat="b in a| filter:{'category':'B'}">{{b}}</div>
```